# Can I loop files for get MD5 with java Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am currently trying to get a list of files with a list of your Hash in MD5.

Being something that can take a long time I'm trying to do it with threads, but fail updating views with list.nullPointer

The code is the following some idea

```
for (File file : files) {
            ListRunable listaRunable = new ListRunable(file);
            listRunable.start();
            String md5 = listRunable.getMD5();
            file = listRunable.getFile();
            updateHashes(file, md5);
        }
```

Some idea why it fails?

Comment: Use an `ExecutorService`, pass each file in as a separate task

Comment: You need to provide more code e.g. what exactly is your `ListRunnable`. Also it would be advisable to use `ForkJoinPool` instead of starting the threads manually (assuming `ListRunnable extends Thread`).

Comment: How many files are you talking about? Is this for a checksum of each file?

Comment: start() just starts the thread and returns immediately. So you can't expect the result to be there immediately after calling start(). If the resut was there, then it would mean that start() waits until the thread is finished, and using threads would then have no purpose: you would end up doing things sequentially. You're also asking about an exception without giving its stack trace, indicating precisely what and where somthing is wrong. Threads are acomplex matter. Learn the basics first.

Comment: This is an I/O bound problem. Using multiple threads will be of little help (or make it even worse) if you don't have several physical disks.

Comment: What do you recommend?

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES : as an exercise, you can try to multithread and see what happens. As a pure performance gain, many CPUs (or whatever processor) are faster at calculating MD5 than the disks are at reading files. In such a scenario, multithreading won't be of help, you have to find a way to access the files' bytes faster. (e.g use SSD storage instead of long term storage on spinning disks ; or make sure the files are in the system cache ; or store them in a compressed form with less bytes to read ; or pre-compute/cache MD5s when files are first manipulated somewhere else in your app...)